# Intermediate Ramaze Routing Help Please

Tags: ruby, rest, ramaze

Part 1:

I have a call to `layout(:default){|path,wish| wish !~ /rss|atom|json/}` but requests to `/foo/bar.json` seem to think `wish` is `html` and uses the layout anyway. How can I fix this?

Part 2:

I want to route `/path/to/file.ext` so that it calls the method `to` on the controller mapped to `/path` and uses `ext` when formulating the return. Is there a better (more elegant) way to do this than passing the 'file.ext' to the `to` method, parsing it, and doing cases? This question would have been more succinct if I had written, how does one do REST with Ramaze? There appears to be a Google Groups answer to this one, but I can't access it for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ToController < Controller

  map '/path/to'
  provide( :json, :type => "application/json") { |action, val| val.to_json } 

  def bar
    @barInfo = {name: "Fonzie's", poison: "milk"}
  end

end
```

This controller returns plain JSON when you request `/path/to/bar.json` and uses the layout+view wrapping when you request `/path/to/bar` (Ramaze has no default layout setting, the layout in this example comes from the Controller parent class).

Comment: Works perfectly! I can take out the horrible kludge I had in place now :)

Comment: Cool. Ramaze routing can be confusing but usually there is a nice way to fill any particular need you may have. The template resolution system is very flexible too, and confusing sometimes.